# Capacitive Touch Sensor: "When touched for 100 ms"

Tags: arduino

I'm facing a programming question in which I want to trigger some code whenever a capacitive touch sensor has been touched for 100 ms (to distinguish false positives in my prototype). My sensor is touched by this code

```
if (digitalRead(touchPin))
```

Now whenever it has been touched for 100ms I want some other code (for instance, activating a LED) to run. I can't really seem to find a solution because my `startTime = millis()` variable keeps resetting.

Does anyone know how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Have your tried making a function and calling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need a bool variable, to store last state (TRUE if touched and FALSE if not)
2. Also, you need to store time when it has been changed to TRUE. Time could be taken by millis() function
3. If your bool variable is true, check, if time passed is more than your 100 ms.

So:

```cpp
// In your global scope:
...
// Last touch state
bool isTouched = FALSE;
// time, when last touch happened
int touched_t = 0;

// In your loop:
...
bool isTouchedNow = (digitalRead(touchPin) == HIGH);
// Touch state is changed till last measure:
if (isTouchedNow != isTouched)
{
   // Set "last isTouched state" to new one
   isTouched = isTouchedNow;
   // If it wasn't touched before, store current time (else zero):
   touched_t = isTouched ? millis() : 0;       
}
else //If touch state isn't changed till last time:
{
   //If state was "touched" and now it "touched", and 100ms has passed:
   if (isTouched && touched_t > 0 && millis() - touched_t > 100)
   {
      // Call your function, that should be called, 
      // whan sensor is touched for 100 ms (activate a LED of something)
      DOTHESTUFF();
   }
}
...
```

Comment: Legend, solved my problem. Thanks. Note tho, in your first if statement your first variable is spelled wrong, should be: `isTouchedNow`